# XSLT select text without children

Tags: xslt, xpath

XML:

`<data><ph>Foo</ph>Bar</data>`

XSL:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="data/ph"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="data"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="data/ph">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="data">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

When the XSL selects the text in the /data/ with `<xsl:template match="data"><xsl:value-of select="."/>` it is also selecting the text in the child entity data/ph. How do I point to only the text of /data/, without including the text of /data/ph/ ?

My output should be: FooBar, and not FooFooBar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When the XSL selects the text in the `/data/` with `<xsl:template
>   match="data"><xsl:value-of select="."/>` it is also selecting the text
>   in the child entity `data/ph`. How do I point to only the text of
>   `/data/`, without including the text of `/data/ph/` ?

**Use**:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="text()"/>
```

This copies all text node-children of the current node.

**With this correction, the whole transformation becomes**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="data/ph"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="data"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="data/ph">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="data">
        <xsl:copy-of select="text()"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**and when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<data><ph>Foo</ph>Bar</data>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
FooBar
```

Comment: Perfect, so I rewrote it as:

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="data/ph"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="data/text()"/>
    </xsl:template>